# Is it possible to extract intersection list that contains duplicate values?

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I want to get an intersection of lists where duplication is not eliminated.
And I hope that the method is a fast way not to use loops.
Below was my attempt, but this method failed because duplicates were removed.

```
a = ['a','b','c','f']
b = ['a','b','b','o','k']

tmp = list(set(a) & set(b))
>>>tmp
>>>['b','a']
```

I want the result to be `['a', 'b', 'b']`.

In this method, `'a'` is a fixed value and `'b'` is a variable value.

And the concept of extracting `'a'` value from `'b'`.

Is there a way to extract a list of cross-values ​​that do not remove duplicate values?

Comment: Set operations treat lists as sets and remove all duplicates.

Comment: @Austin that wouldn't include duplicates in a

Comment: So far, 'a' and 'b' are the common items. 'a' occurs with multiplicity 1 on both sets. 'b' occurs with multiplicity 2 on list b, and 1 on list a. Your intersection lists all the common elements repeated by the maximum multiplicity. Do you mean a set like this?

Comment: The answer is yes. Convert the list into a datastructure which duplicates are removed and are represented as a multiplicity counter..

Comment: to Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩ ᛗ  
I think that's right. I am not good at writing English. I apologize for that.

Comment: to Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩ ᛗ
ㄴIf you have a document about the way you said, can you give me a link?

Comment: Are you okay if the solution contains loop statements?

Comment: This code is part of a complex function, and there is a lot of data to be computed, so I hope to have as few loops as possible. If there is no other way, please suggesting a way to use a minimal number of loops.

Comment: You can use up to one loop. The inner loop in my code can be replaced with itertools. It is an iterative algorithm after all.

Comment: Additionally, how much of these arrays are involved in computing the intersection? Is it variable? I have provided a 3-array case using just two explicit loop statements, which can be reduced to one.

Comment: Actually if you want the intersection without removing of duplicates the result must be `[‘a’, ‘b’, ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘b’]`.

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit so you should explain how **duplicates are handled** in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be

```
good = set(a)
result = [x for x in b if x in good]
```

there are two loops here; one is the set-building loop of `set` (that is implemented in C, a hundred of times faster than whatever you can do in Python) the other is the comprehension and runs in the interpreter.
The first loop is done to avoid a linear search in `a` for each element of `b` (if `a` becomes big this can be a serious problem).

Note that using `filter` instead is probably not going to gain much (if anything) because despite the `filter` loop being in C, for each element it will have to get back to the interpreter to call the filtering function.

Note that if you care about speed then probably Python is not a good choice... for example may be PyPy would be better here and in this case just writing an optimal algorithm explicitly should be ok (avoiding re-searching `a` for duplicates when they are consecutive in `b` like happens in your example)

```
good = set(a)
res = []
i = 0
while i < len(b):
    x = b[i]
    if x in good:
        while i < len(b) and b[i] == x:  # is?
            res.append(x)
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Of course in performance optimization the only real way is try and measure with real data on the real system... guessing works less and less as technology advances and becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>a = ['a','b','c','f']
>>b = ['a','b','b','o','k']
>>items = set(a)
>>found = [i for i in b if i in items]
>>items
{'f', 'a', 'c', 'b'}
>>found
['a', 'b', 'b']
```

This should do your work.

Comment: I think you meant `[i for i in b if i in items]` to make use of the fast membership test in a set.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear how duplicates are handled when performing an intersection of lists which contain duplicate elements, as you have given only one test case and its expected result, and you did not explain duplicate handling.

According to how keeping duplicates work currently, the common elements are `'a'` and `'b'`, and the intersection list lists `'a'` with multiplicity 1 and `'b'` with multiplicity 2. Note `'a'` occurs once on both lists *a* and *b*, but `'b'` occurs twice on *b*. The intersection list lists the common element with multiplicity equal to the list having that element at the *maximum* multiplicity.

The answer is **yes**. However, a loop may implicitly be called - though you want your code to not explicitly use any loop statements. This algorithm, however, will always be iterative.

**Step 1:** Create the intersection set, `Intersect` that does not contain duplicates (You already done that). Convert to list to keep indexing.

**Step 2:** Create a second array, `IntersectD`. Create a new variable `Freq` which counts the maximum number of occurrences for that common element, using `count`. Use `Intersect` and `Freq` to append the element `Intersect[k]` a number of times depending on its corresponding `Freq[k]`.

An example code with 3 lists would be

```
a = ['a','b','c','1','1','1','1','2','3','o']
b = ['a','b','b','o','1','o','1']
c = ['a','a','a','b','1','2']

intersect = list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c)) # 3-set case
intersectD = []

for k in range(len(intersect)):
  cmn = intersect[k]
  freq = max(a.count(cmn), b.count(cmn), c.count(cmn)) # 3-set case
  for i in range(freq): # Can be done with itertools
    intersectD.append(cmn)

>>> intersectD
>>> ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

For cases involving more than two lists, `freq` for this common element can be computed using a more complex set intersection and max expression. If using a list of lists, `freq` can be computed using an inner loop. You can also replace the inner i-loop with an itertools expression from [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item/23909767#23909767).

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on not using `for` **explicitly** then this will work:

```
>>> list(filter(a.__contains__, b))
['a', 'b', 'b']
```

But directly calling magic methods like `__contains__` is not a recommended practice to the best of my knowledge, so consider this instead:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in a, b))
['a', 'b', 'b']
```

And if you want to improve the lookup in `a` from *O(n)* to *O(1)* then create a `set` of it first:

```
>>> a_set = set(a)
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in a_set, b))
['a', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not faster than a loop and finally you probably still need a loop to extract the result. Anyway...

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['a','a','b','c','f']
b = ['a','b','b','o','k']

count_b = Counter(b)
count_ab = Counter(set(b)-set(a))
count_b - count_ab

#=> Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

---

I mean, if `res` holds the result, you need to:

```
[ val for sublist in [ [s] * n for s, n in res.items() ] for val in sublist ]
#=> ['a', 'b', 'b']
```